# How do I reuse xib files across the app? Or does the IBOutlets get inherited?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created xib file which is sort of a template to the different table view cells I will be having. The xib has a left label and a button on the right. The actions will be different when button is clicked, so I created a .swift file for the xib which has outlets connected to it and then I created 2 sub-classes out of the .swift file which will basically set the target on button and perform different actions. However this doesn't work and the controls are not showing up on the app.

***Custom xib file and base swift class for the xib:***

[image]

[image]

***Sub-class from LeftLabelRightButton swift class:***

[image]

***Registering xib in view controller and cell for row at index path:***

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "LeftLabelRightButton", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell") as? SampleSubClass {
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none
        cell.leftLabel.text = "Hello World"
        cell.leftLabel.textAlignment = .left
     }
}
```

I am not getting any errors with this, but I don't see the label or the button if I dequeue the cell as SampleSubClass.

***If I do this then I see the label and button on the app:***

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell") as? LeftLabelRightButton {
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none
        cell.leftLabel.text = "Hello World"
        cell.leftLabel.textAlignment = .left
     }
}
```

Can I dequeue the cell as sub-class? Does the outlet get inherited? My guess is with sub-class the outlets are not getting inherited.

Comment: Your problem is that the NIB file specifies the class and it can only specify one class. So while your subclass will inherit the outlet properties you have no way of dequeing an instance of the subclass from the nib. You would have to duplicate the nib and specify the subclass in that duplicate. You can then register a different reuse identifier against the nib. However, if the only difference is the button action then you probably don't even need a subclass. You can just inject the button handling code via a closure or use delegation

Answer (score 0):

First question : Yes. You can reuse xib across the app. Just register it to your `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`.

Second one : Yes also, but you can't use `dequeueReusableCell`. So i think it's useless.